# how to sum time column and avoid null fields in ssrs 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have column of time values and i want to sum these values but when one field is null an error is shown **#error** ,, i used iif (isnothing(attTime),0, attTime) condition but this integer error then i used 00:00 but it appears 12 hour and sum 12

this code that i used

> = Right("0" & Sum(CInt(Left(CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"),2)), "DataSet1")
>       + Floor(Sum(CInt(Right(CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"),2)), "DataSet1") / 60),2)
>     & ":" & Sum(CInt(Right(CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"),2)), "DataSet1") Mod 60

so please i want to sum the fields and avoid the null fields

Comment: DO you have control over your database query ? If yes then post your query ? And it is also not clear what you are trying to do by your expression to complicated. Can you explain with example . May be there simple solution what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: "select hoursAtt from attendanceTable"  so i want sum hours as total  but  but null fields prevent me

Comment: Can't you change your query to `select hoursAtt from attendanceTable where hoursAtt is not NULL` ?

Comment: No.. i want to show the empty field

Answer (score 0):

use

`iif (isnothing(attTime),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"))`

in your expressions

Comment: "00:00" is not time so it get error and also when convert it is became 12 so   the total increase 12

Comment: You don't have to convert it to date again. In my expression it will be used as a string only. Use it directly in Left function.

Comment: i did hat but get error  ...this is the query ""      =Right("0" & Sum(CInt(Left(CDate(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"))),2)), "DataSet1")
    + Floor(Sum(CInt(Right(CDate(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"))),2)), "DataSet1") / 60),2)
  & ":" & Sum(CInt(Right(CDate(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"))),2)), "DataSet1") Mod 60

Comment: Remove the outer CDate e.g. `Right("0" & Sum(CInt(Left(CDate(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"))),2))` to `Right("0" & Sum(CInt(Left(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString(),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"))),2))`

Comment: = Right("0" & Sum(CInt(Left(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm")),2)), "DataSet1")
    + Floor(Sum(CInt(Right(CDate(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"))),2)), "DataSet1") / 60),2)
  & ":" & Sum(CInt(Right(CDate(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"))),2)), "DataSet1") Mod 60

Comment: and this is the error                                                                        TimeAtt
10:50
11:00
12:12
Null
total #Error

Answer (score 0):

![TimeAtt columns][1]

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    
  </td> 
  <td>
    TimeAtt
  </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>
    
  </td> <td>
    10:50
  </td> </tr>
 <tr> <td>
    
  </td>  <td>
   11:00
  </td> </tr>
  <tr><td>
    
  </td><td>
    12:12
  </td> </tr>
 <tr> <td>
    
  </td>  <td>
    Null
  </td> </tr>
  <tr><td>total</td><td>#Error</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and this is the query
= Right("0" & Sum(CInt(Left(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm")),2)), "DataSet1")
    + Floor(Sum(CInt(Right(CDate(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"))),2)), "DataSet1") / 60),2)
  & ":" & Sum(CInt(Right(CDate(iif (isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()),"00:00", CDate(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()).ToString("hh:mm"))),2)), "DataSet1") Mod 60

Comment: Please post this in comments, not as an answer.

Comment: isnothing(Fields!timeAtt.Value.ToString()) => remove ToString() from here and other occurring.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this might be simpler if you handle the underlying query.
Will this work?

```
SELECT ISNULL(hoursAtt,'00:00:00') AS hoursAtt FROM attendanceTable
```